# Python - increasing efficiency of a Tree data structure

Tags: python, performance, tree

i'm currently working on a Tree data structure in python. At the moment, i am trying to calculate subtree values, where a subtree value equals the largest value of a node in a given node's subtree. E.g. For the given tree:

```
       A(5)
       / \
     C(2) D(8)
      |
     B(10)
```

The subtree value of C would be 10, the subtree value of A would be 10 and the subtree value of D would be 8 etc.
I have the following code for propagating the subtree value up the tree (as each node has a "subtree_value" element) but i cannot seem to improve my algorithm. Originally i used recursion and then switched to nested loops as i am not very experienced in recursion. However, is there any way i can do this without the need for a nested loop?

```
        node = subtree_a
        while node.parent != None: #iterates up the list until it reaches the root node
            children = node.parent.children
            for child in children:
                if (child.subtree_value > node.parent.subtree_value): #updates subtree value of parent based on largest child key
                    node.parent.set_subtree_val(child.subtree_value) 
            node = node.parent
```

Comment: Use a recursive function.

Comment: Is this code run on every insert and delete? There is at least one early exit condition when inserting - when a node's `subtree_value` is not updated you do not need to update the parent since it should not change

Comment: Do you really need to remember each node's subtree value? Why not just compute it (for a specific node) when needed?

Comment: I am trying to swap the positions between two separate subtrees in a tree. Thus, it is called every time this swap() function is called. And i am not too great at recursion that's why i'm not using it or trying to compute the subtree value when needed.